# How to transfer iPhoto slide show to view on PC from iPhone

Tags: photos.app

I have created a slide show on my iPhone using iPhoto. How do I get that onto my PC or convert it into a video / mov or something?

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way is to save (Export) your slide show as QuickTime.mov file.

Use or [download](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#quicktime) QuickTime for your PC.